# I can not get values form RadioButtonFor List in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I am working on the project what have View with different layout on Mobile view and desktop view. So my solution is creating on View with 2 tables to define different elements for each view. But they will be bind data from the same Model. Please take a look at my code below:

**View**

```
<table class="pc" style="border: 1px solid #eeecdc">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.SelectedOption, 1)
        </td>
        <td> @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.SelectedOption, 2)
        </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>


 <table class="mb" style="border: 1px solid #eeecdc">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.SelectedOption, 1, new { @Name = "selectedOption_mb" })
        </td>
        <td> @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.SelectedOption, 2, new { @Name = "selectedOption_mb" })
        </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

**Model**

```
public class TestViewModel
{
   public TestViewModel(string pageName)
    {
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the answer scales.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The answer scales.</value>
    public int SelectedOption { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public partial class TestController
    {

       [HttpPost]
       [ModelStateToTempData]
       public virtual ActionResult TestSave(TestViewModel model)
       {
         var value= model.SelectedOption;
       }
     }
```

**Result**

With Desktop View : I can get value.

With Mobile View : I can not get value ( it's always null).

Please help me to get value from mobile view. I don't know what I have done wrong.

please take a look at the attachment about PC and Mobile view it's reason I have to define both html on the one View.

**Desktop**
[image]

**Mobile**
[image]

Thank you so much!

Comment: `new { @Name = "selectedOption_mb" }` changes the `name` attribute which no longer matches the name of your model property so it cannot be set by the `DefaultModelBinder`. But why are you doing this. You now generating twice as much html as needed and sending it all across the wire, degrading performance.

Comment: I have just revised my question, that why I have to define two html on same view.

Comment: No, you approaching this the wrong way. You need to include just the html for one or the other based on the device. And I have explained why is does not (and can never) work

Comment: you mean we should use responsive right? but please double check my design, you can see the structure of table will be changed <td> will be <tr> and question text will be on top instead in center as Desktop view. I tried Jquery but no way to work..

Comment: No I do not mean that. Your rendering both tables but showing one one or the other. You need to use that same logic to render only one or the other in the first place.

Comment: yes, I see. Thank you so much @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason is your name of Radio button on Mobile View is not correct and it's not matched and can not be set by the `DefaultModelBinder`

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.SelectedOption, 1, new { @Name = "selectedOption_mb" })
```

I totally understand that you want to get value from `HttpGet` method. Data will be shown both Mobile and Desktop Views.

In this case, if you want to define both view with different element on the one `View`. you should define more properties for Mobile view from `Model`. Please refer my code below:

**Model**

```
public class TestViewModel
{
     public int? SelectedOption { get; set; }
     public int? SelectedOption_mb { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
<table class="mb" style="border: 1px solid #eeecdc">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td> @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.SelectedOption_mb, 1)
    </td>
    <td> @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.SelectedOption_mb, 2)
    </td>
 </tr>
```

**Controller**

```
var value= model.SelectedOption!=nul?
           model.SelectedOption:model.SelectedOption_mb!=null?
                                model.SelectedOption_mb:null;
```

Hopefully, it would be helpful.